# What is the interpretation of sklearn's linear perceptron coefficients?

Tags: scikit-learn, perceptron

I'm stumped as to why this example doesn't do a better job fitting the data, I suspect it has to do with my interpretation of the perceptron object's coefficients.  Note that I'm interested in the `sklearn` object's implementation, not necessarily the math behind a perceptron.

It may help to know the example below yields:

```
perc.coef_ = array([[ -34. , -681.9,  222. ]])
```

[image: Poor fit (see code below)]

```py
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.linear_model import Perceptron
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

# clean data
df = sns.load_dataset('penguins')
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df_no_torg = df.loc[df['island'] != 'Torgersen', :]

# extract data
x = df_no_torg.loc[:, ('bill_length_mm', 'flipper_length_mm')].to_numpy()
y = df_no_torg.loc[:, 'island'].to_numpy() == 'Biscoe'
# manual bias term (one less thing to consider)
x = np.hstack((np.ones((x.shape[0], 1)), x))

# init / fit perceptron
perc = Perceptron(fit_intercept=False)
perc.fit(x, y)

def get_boundary(x):
    w = perc.coef_[0]
    m = - w[1] / w[2]
    b = - w[0] / w[2]
    return m * x + b

# plot results
x = np.linspace(30, 60, 100)
b = get_boundary(x)
with PdfPages('penguin_scatter_bound.pdf') as pdf:
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
    plt.plot(x, b, label='boundary')
    sns.scatterplot(data=df_no_torg, x='bill_length_mm', y='flipper_length_mm', hue='island')
    pdf.savefig()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here lies in the hyperparameters. `perc.n_iter_` is 6 after running your code; [according to the defaults in the api](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Perceptron.html), the default value for `n_iter_no_change` is 5, so it looks like there was no improvement for the first five iterations and training simply terminated (despite the documentation also saying that `n_iter_no_change` only matters when `early_stopping` is `True`).

By playing around with the number of iterations and step size, I was able to get a much better fit (`perc.fit(x, y, tol=None, max_iter=20000)`).[image]